# react native touchable with feedback exists?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If I click on a Input field, then they keyboard is active. If I want to remove the keyboard with a Click I can use this:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss()} 
...
```

Ok But maybe the keyboard is open and I want to click a box or an Item with a onPress function. So If the keyboard is open and maybe I want to click a Link, then the keyboard dismiss but the link wasnt pressed. I cant click anything when the keyboard is open now I want you to ask how I can click an Link maybe where the keyboard is open. Maybe a function like "TouchableWithFeedBack".

It is the same action like Instagram where you can find User. If the keyboard is open and you want to click the person, it goes to User and they keyboard dismiss. In my case only the Keyboard dismiss.

I hope you understand me

Comment: use: keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'} in the ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

When you add the other items (links or buttons) as children of the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component, then the interaction seems to work fine:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Alert, Keyboard, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TextInput, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title="Press Me" onPress={() => Alert.alert('Button Pressed')} />
          <TextInput placeholder="Input" autoFocus />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```